# CSS container height issue

Tags: html, css

My container is not touching my footer for the majority of cases and I'm not sure what's going on.

So here is my CSS code:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container"> 
  <section>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  </section>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Content</div>
</body>
```

So I have all of the heights set for parent elements,but there's still a big gap between the container and the footer. In cases where the content takes up the whole page, the footer and container ends up touching, but the content for some reason gets lost in the footer. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You've given it 100% height, so it will take up 100% of the height of its content - not 100% of the height of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height based on percentage are tricky. vh is much better for such purposes.

Here is the solution: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkp7f73f/1/)

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This works when I have content that fits on the screen, but when I have content that needs scrolling, it doesn't work since overflow is set to hidden. How do I get around that issue?

Comment: You have used position absolute for footer.  Thats bad if you are planning to have more content.  You can either just remove overflow,  and set bottom:0 to the footer with yiur last container touching the deadline

Answer (score 1):

Make one adjustment to your CSS:

Add `height: 100%` to the `html` element.

```
html {
    height: 100%; /* NEW */
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

This will clear the way for all child elements to recognize their percentage heights, and the container will expand. Your `min-height: 100%` will still work because [`min-height` overrides `height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height).

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/au6tcodc/

(You'll notice a vertical scrollbar on the container in the demo. This is caused by the `overflow: auto` declaration in `#container`. If you want to remove the scrollbar switch to `overflow: hidden` ([see all `overflow` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)).